# Android R Class cannot resloved variable

Tags: android, eclipse

When I add a new activity, add the xml file, and add the palette on the xml file, my R class cannot contain it automatically. Anyone who knows the cause, I beg you let me know, thanks..

Comment: -Just restart your eclipse

Comment: clean the project.R class will be generated .

Comment: clean your project and rebuild

Comment: clean and rebuild your project. this is answered here many times please  search before posting

Answer (score 0):

R class should be auto generated when the build has succeeded. There can be errors in your xml file which prevents R class to be generated. Check console for errors.

Answer (score 0):

Also check if you have imported it to your class on your class headers. Usually causes errorsif its imported.